# How to render text with QOpenGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt

In older version of Qt there was [QGLWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qglwidget.html), with a nice function called [renderText](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qglwidget.html#renderText). Now I'm using [QOpenGLWidget](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qopenglwidget.html) class and the functionality for rendering text is missing.

Is there a easy way to render text using QOpenGLWidget? I won't like to build the whole text rendering with OpenGL from scratch...

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/freetype-gl/

Answer (score 5):

You can implement this functionality by yourself based on the old Qt source code.

In your OpenGL widget class inherited from QOpenGLWidget (in this example it's GLBox) you have to implement the following methods:

renderText:

```
void GLBox::renderText(D3DVECTOR &textPosWorld, QString text)
{
    int width = this->width();
    int height = this->height();

    GLdouble model[4][4], proj[4][4];
    GLint view[4];
    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, &model[0][0]);
    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, &proj[0][0]);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, &view[0]);
    GLdouble textPosX = 0, textPosY = 0, textPosZ = 0;

    project(textPosWorld.x, textPosWorld.y, textPosWorld.z, 
                &model[0][0], &proj[0][0], &view[0],
                &textPosX, &textPosY, &textPosZ);

    textPosY = height - textPosY; // y is inverted

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(Qt::yellow);
    painter.setFont(QFont("Helvetica", 8));
    painter.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::TextAntialiasing);
    painter.drawText(textPosX, textPosY, text); // z = pointT4.z + distOverOp / 4
    painter.end();
}
```

project:

```
inline GLint GLBox::project(GLdouble objx, GLdouble objy, GLdouble objz,
    const GLdouble model[16], const GLdouble proj[16],
    const GLint viewport[4],
    GLdouble * winx, GLdouble * winy, GLdouble * winz)
{
    GLdouble in[4], out[4];

    in[0] = objx;
    in[1] = objy;
    in[2] = objz;
    in[3] = 1.0;
    transformPoint(out, model, in);
    transformPoint(in, proj, out);

    if (in[3] == 0.0)
        return GL_FALSE;

    in[0] /= in[3];
    in[1] /= in[3];
    in[2] /= in[3];

    *winx = viewport[0] + (1 + in[0]) * viewport[2] / 2;
    *winy = viewport[1] + (1 + in[1]) * viewport[3] / 2;

    *winz = (1 + in[2]) / 2;
    return GL_TRUE;
}
```

and finally transformPoint:

```
inline void GLBox::transformPoint(GLdouble out[4], const GLdouble m[16], const GLdouble in[4])
{
#define M(row,col)  m[col*4+row]
    out[0] =
        M(0, 0) * in[0] + M(0, 1) * in[1] + M(0, 2) * in[2] + M(0, 3) * in[3];
    out[1] =
        M(1, 0) * in[0] + M(1, 1) * in[1] + M(1, 2) * in[2] + M(1, 3) * in[3];
    out[2] =
        M(2, 0) * in[0] + M(2, 1) * in[1] + M(2, 2) * in[2] + M(2, 3) * in[3];
    out[3] =
        M(3, 0) * in[0] + M(3, 1) * in[1] + M(3, 2) * in[2] + M(3, 3) * in[3];
#undef M
}
```

If you need renderText() because you have to port your Qt4 application to Qt5 just make sure to change the signature of the function provided here to

```
void GLBox::renderText(double x, double y, double z, const QString & str, const QFont & font = QFont(), int listBase = 2000)
```

and you don't have to worry about this anymore.

Comment: You can use `gluProject` instead of reimplementing it with `project`.

Answer (score 5):

I ended up doing a solution similar to what @jaba wrote. I also noticed some graphical corruption unless I called painter.end() at the end of the method.

```
void MapCanvas::renderText(double x, double y, double z, const QString &str, const QFont & font = QFont()) {
    // Identify x and y locations to render text within widget
    int height = this->height();
    GLdouble textPosX = 0, textPosY = 0, textPosZ = 0;
    project(x, y, 0f, &textPosX, &textPosY, &textPosZ);
    textPosY = height - textPosY; // y is inverted

    // Retrieve last OpenGL color to use as a font color
    GLdouble glColor[4];
    glGetDoublev(GL_CURRENT_COLOR, glColor);
    QColor fontColor = QColor(glColor[0], glColor[1], glColor[2], glColor[3]);

    // Render text
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(fontColor);
    painter.setFont(font);
    painter.drawText(textPosX, textPosY, text);
    painter.end();
}
```

Comment: You have to multiply your QColor arguments by 255

Answer (score 3):

As you seem to be wanting to draw 2D text, use [QPainter::drawText()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawText). See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#painting-techniques) for info about using QPainter on a QOpenGLWidget. For using antialiasing for text rendering on QOpenGLWidgets see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586415/qt-text-rendering-in-qopenglwidget).
If you want to draw 2.5D text (2D text moving with the 3D scene) it is not "too hard" to roll your own classes. Use QFont and QFontMetricsF to build a texture for your font glyphs, build some quads for each glyph into a VBO and draw the proper quads for the glyphs in a string...

Answer (score 0):

QPainter::drawText on a QOpenGLWidget relies on GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT being set to 4, otherwise characters will look corrupt/scrambled.

If you have this problem in your application, make sure to call

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
```

before drawing the text.
(see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-65496 for more info)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference for anybody coming here with a similar issue - I had a similar issue as described in [Urs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51557719/671366): When showing text on the OpenGL widget with `drawText`, some letters, sometimes whole words, were missing. Yet the mentioned `glPixelStorei` call did not change anything.

What I noticed when reading the [QOpenGLWidget painting documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#painting-techniques) was the `QOpenGLFunction` related stuff - and indeed the affected widget in our case did not use QOpenGLFunction yet, but apparently called OpenGL functions directly - and this lead to the weird text display.

Deriving from `QOpenGLFunction` and calling `initializeOpenGLFunctions` in `initializeGL` seems to have fixed the problems.

Edit: No luck - My problem seems to be an intermittent one that is only appearing occasionally (it's not reproducible every time I run the program). I guess I'll look into Qt OpenGL context debugging next.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I needed to draw axis and corresponding ticks. In Qt4, I can use the following code:

```
for (int i = _Ymin; i <= _Ymax; i = i + _yGrid)
{
  double yPos = (_Ymax-i)*_yscaleF*_yscalingF;
  double xPos = -_xmin*_xscaleF-_shiftX;
  if(yPos < (_Ymax-_Ymin)*_yscaleF-_shiftY+1)
  {
      glBegin(GL_LINES);
      glVertex2f(xPos-2, yPos);
      glVertex2f(xPos+2, yPos);
      glEnd();
     renderText (xPos - offset,yPos+5 , 0, QString::number(i/10.0));
  }
}
glScalef(_xscalingF,_yscalingF,0);
```

However, when I try to migrate my code to Qt6, there's no `renderText` anymore.
After searching on the web and investigating the source code of `renderText`, finally I found the solution, one needs to save/load gl status:

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex2f(xPos-4, yPos);
glVertex2f(xPos+4, yPos);
glEnd();
qt_save_gl_state();
renderText(xPos - offset,yPos+5 , QString::number(i/10.0));
qt_restore_gl_state();
```

Here are the def of qt_save_gl_state, renderText, qt_restore_gl_state:

```
static void qt_save_gl_state()
{
    glPushClientAttrib(GL_CLIENT_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);
    glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);
    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();

    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}
static void qt_restore_gl_state()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPopAttrib();
    glPopClientAttrib();
}
void GLWidgetnew::renderText(double x, double y, const QString text)
{
    GLdouble textPosX = x, textPosY = y;
    // Retrieve last OpenGL color to use as a font color
    GLdouble glColor[4];
    glGetDoublev(GL_CURRENT_COLOR, glColor);
    QColor fontColor = QColor(glColor[0]*255, glColor[1]*255, 
    glColor[2]*255, glColor[3]*255);
    // Render text
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.translate(float(_shiftX),float(_shiftY)); //This is for my own mouse event (scaling) 
                                
    painter.setPen(fontColor);
    QFont f;
    f.setPixelSize(10);
    painter.setFont(f);
    painter.drawText(textPosX, textPosY, text);
    painter.end();
}
```

src code of the project can be found here [QtSignalProcessing](https://github.com/QtSignalProcessing/QtSignalProcessing/blob/qt6/src/glwidgetnew.cpp)