# Qt: text rendering in QOpenGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I want to draw text labels on QOpenGLWidget. I tried to use QPainter for this task, but had no success - text looks ugly and non antialiased. It is also looks ugly in Qt OpenGL/2dpainting samples. However text rendering is significantly better in QML controls which also use OpenGL backend. Here http://blog.qt.io/blog/2011/07/15/text-rendering-in-the-qml-scene-graph/ I have found a technique that is used in QML. Is there a way to use that technique to draw text in QOpenGLWidget?

PS: May be the right way to go is to embed all my scene inside QSGSceneGraph of QQuickWidget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you create your QGL/QopenGLWidget with a surface format that supports multisampling for antialiasing:

```
QSurfaceFormat format = QSurfaceFormat::defaultFormat();
format.setSamples(4);
QOpenGLWidget * glWidget = new QOpenGLWidget;
glWidget->setFormat(format);
```

Then, when using a QPainter on that widget, make sure you turn on antialiasing:

```
QPainter painter(paintDevice);
painter.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::TextAntialiasing);
```

Then paint your text.

Answer (score 1):

Reimplement the old QOGLWidget's renderText() for convenient text rendering.
This way text will move with the scene. If you want a static version you can simplify it.

Inherited a class from QOpenGLWidget (in this example it's GLBox) with the following methods:

renderText:

```
void GLBox::renderText(D3DVECTOR &textPosWorld, QString text)
{
    int width = this->width();
    int height = this->height();

    GLdouble model[4][4], proj[4][4];
    GLint view[4];
    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, &model[0][0]);
    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, &proj[0][0]);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, &view[0]);
    GLdouble textPosX = 0, textPosY = 0, textPosZ = 0;

    project(textPosWorld.x, textPosWorld.y, textPosWorld.z, 
                &model[0][0], &proj[0][0], &view[0],
                &textPosX, &textPosY, &textPosZ);

    textPosY = height - textPosY; // y is inverted

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(Qt::yellow);
    painter.setFont(QFont("Helvetica", 8));
    painter.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::TextAntialiasing);
    painter.drawText(textPosX, textPosY, text); // z = pointT4.z + distOverOp / 4
    painter.end();
}
```

project:

```
inline GLint GLBox::project(GLdouble objx, GLdouble objy, GLdouble objz,
    const GLdouble model[16], const GLdouble proj[16],
    const GLint viewport[4],
    GLdouble * winx, GLdouble * winy, GLdouble * winz)
{
    GLdouble in[4], out[4];

    in[0] = objx;
    in[1] = objy;
    in[2] = objz;
    in[3] = 1.0;
    transformPoint(out, model, in);
    transformPoint(in, proj, out);

    if (in[3] == 0.0)
        return GL_FALSE;

    in[0] /= in[3];
    in[1] /= in[3];
    in[2] /= in[3];

    *winx = viewport[0] + (1 + in[0]) * viewport[2] / 2;
    *winy = viewport[1] + (1 + in[1]) * viewport[3] / 2;

    *winz = (1 + in[2]) / 2;
    return GL_TRUE;
}
```

and finally transformPoint:

```
inline void GLBox::transformPoint(GLdouble out[4], const GLdouble m[16], const GLdouble in[4])
{
#define M(row,col)  m[col*4+row]
    out[0] =
        M(0, 0) * in[0] + M(0, 1) * in[1] + M(0, 2) * in[2] + M(0, 3) * in[3];
    out[1] =
        M(1, 0) * in[0] + M(1, 1) * in[1] + M(1, 2) * in[2] + M(1, 3) * in[3];
    out[2] =
        M(2, 0) * in[0] + M(2, 1) * in[1] + M(2, 2) * in[2] + M(2, 3) * in[3];
    out[3] =
        M(3, 0) * in[0] + M(3, 1) * in[1] + M(3, 2) * in[2] + M(3, 3) * in[3];
#undef M
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adding a little rotation to the painter seems to add smoothness to text, but the quality is somewhat mediocre:

```
painter.rotate(0.01);
painter.drawText(textPosX, textPosY, text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble mixing up `QPainter` and `QOpenGLWidet`, in particular using my `QOpenGLWidget` as painter device to render a single text element. As result I got full screen of clear color. All my previous codes seems to be broken. 
So i came up with a different solution using a `QGraphicsScene` as paint device. Subsequently, i render the painter into a `QImage`, which i can use to create a common 2D-`QOpenGLTexture`. This texture can be drawn via `QOpenGLBuffer` buffer as usual.

```
void MyQOpenGLWidget::createTexture(int x, int y, int z, const QString& str, const QFont& font) {
    // create an image of the text with transparent backround
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    scene.addText(str, font);
    QImage img(scene.width(), scene.height(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
    img.fill(QColor(0, 0, 0, 0));
    QPainter painter(&img);
    painter.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);
    scene.render(&painter);

    // store the tex as member somewhere in the QOpenGLWidget
    QOpenGLTexture tex(img);

    // store the bufferindex as member somewhere in the QOpenGLWidget
    int bufferIndex = 0
    /*this is the index corresponding to first element of coords writen into buffer
    -> the number of elements within your tex container times SPRITE_BUFFER_SIZE seems to be reasonable*/

    // calculate coordinates 
    GLfloat coords[SPRITE_BUFFER_SIZE];
    /* [SPRITE_BUFFER_SIZE=20=4*5]->4 corner points
    3-dimensions +2 binary (determine corner point)*/

    // write to buffer 
    buffer.bind()
    buffer.write(sizeof(GLfloat)*bufferIndex, coords, SPRITE_BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(GLfloat))
}
```

Then within `paintGL` we will draw the created texture

```
void MyQOpenGLWidget::paintGL() {
    // somewhere within this function
    tex.bind();
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, bufferIndex / 5, 4);
}
```

Make sure that you use the right blend function.

```
void MyQOpenGLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();

    // somewhere within initializeGL
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
}
```