# QGLWidget RenderText () crashes and text mess up

Tags: qt, opengl, qt5.5

I ported my Qt application from Qt4.8.6 to Qt 5.5.1

After porting GUI crashes randomly at renderText(x, y,z, font). Also sometimes text messes up, instead of letters and numbers bold black rectangles of different sizes are displayed. This code used to work fine with QT 4.8.

My call stack is as follows :-
ig7icd64.dll!000007fedbeeed17()

```
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ig7icd64.dll]  

ig7icd64.dll!000007fedbdbcbe1()     

ig7icd64.dll!000007fedbf3aa39()     

ig7icd64.dll!000007fedbf3a751() 

Qt5Guid.dll!QOpenGLFunctions::glDrawElements(unsigned int mode=5, int count=60, unsigned int type=5123, const void * indices=0x000000e2cd2459c8)  Line 730  C++
Qt5OpenGLd.dll!QGL2PaintEngineExPrivate::drawCachedGlyphs(QFontEngine::GlyphFormat glyphFormat=Format_A8, QStaticTextItem * staticTextItem=0x000000e2fe3a3dd0)  Line 1902   C++

Qt5OpenGLd.dll!QGL2PaintEngineEx::drawTextItem(const QPointF & p={...}, const QTextItem & textItem={...})  Line 1591    C++

Qt5Guid.dll!QPainterPrivate::drawTextItem(const QPointF & p={...}, const QTextItem & _ti={...}, QTextEngine * textEngine=0x0000000000000000)  Line 6501 C++

Qt5Guid.dll!QPainter::drawTextItem(const QPointF & p={...}, const QTextItem & ti={...})  Line 6372  C++

Qt5Guid.dll!QPainter::drawText(const QPointF & p={...}, const QString & str={...}, int tf=0, int justificationPadding=0)  Line 5913 C++

Qt5Guid.dll!QPainter::drawText(const QPointF & p={...}, const QString & str={...})  Line 5697   C++

Qt5Guid.dll!QPainter::drawText(int x=427, int y=175, const QString & s={...})  Line 884 C++

Qt5OpenGLd.dll!qt_gl_draw_text(QPainter * p=0x000000e2ca3c2ee0, int x=427, int y=175, const QString & str={...}, const QFont & font={...})  Line 4776   C++

Qt5OpenGLd.dll!QGLWidget::renderText(double x=8.0000000000000000, double y=0.00000000000000000, double z=0.00000000000000000, const QString & str={...}, const QFont & font={...})  Line 4960   C++
```

Pls help me in this. If anyone has faced similar issue. I am using Windows 8 and drivers are updated. Crash is not replicating on Ubuntu 14 but text mess up on Ubuntu also.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: is Qt 4.8 code also on windows 8? You need to get the effective opengl and glsl versions used in each case. With opengl, the same defect may produce different bugs based on the driver, which explain why Ubuntu not crashing.

Comment: Code is as follows :-

Comment: no need for code. the culprid is in the stack trace.

Comment: You have an Intel GPU. Which one exactly? The general suggestion is: ***upgrade its drivers right now!*** However, some of them are so broken you should not do OpenGL with them.

Comment: @peppe Yes I am using Intel drivers. The Intel® Driver Update Utility reports the following message:
A customized computer manufacturer driver is installed on your computer. The Intel® Driver Update Utility is not able to update the driver.  I have updated drivers from manufacturer's (Dell) site and issue is replicating with updated drivers also.

Comment: Details of Graphics driver are : Adapter String : Intel(R) HD Graphics 2500    Driver version : 9.17.10.2849

Comment: Considering that as of now the [latest driver version for HD 2500 is 15.33.39.4276 (10.18.10.4252)](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/81501/Intel-HD-Graphics-2500-for-3rd-Generation-Intel-Core-Processors)... please let me *not* comment on the quality of Windows drivers and OEMs, ok?

Answer (score 0):

**[QGLWidget is obsolete in Qt5, you must not use it anymore. End of the story](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qglwidget.html)**

The reason for this obsolescence and why you have this weird behavior is the fact that opengl **has deprecated its direct-mode rendering api**, an api Qt4 opengl elements used to rely on. In practical terms deprecated functionality may or may not stay in new drivers depending on the vendor.

Opengl text rendering techniques uses rectangles to render text. For this to work, alpha blending must be enabled. From [this tutorial on opengl](http://www.learnopengl.com/#!In-Practice/Text-Rendering), you can see how the window

[image]

without blending enabled looks like :

[image]

The second image fits pretty well your description

> instead of letters and numbers bold black rectangles of different
>   sizes are displayed.

Comment: Thanks @UmNyobe   Yes, I had similar text rendered. So I need to completely replace QGLWidget with QOpenGLWidget? Is there some work around as I am working on legacy code and it will be a big change.

Comment: There is no work around I know of if you want to be future proof. It is easy to see the mapping between QGLWidget methods, old nativeopengl methods and their replacement . It is not a complex process, but you need to know how opengl works. I had to go through a similar phase myself. Look at question like [How to render text with QOpenGLWidget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216001/how-to-render-text-with-qopenglwidget) if you try to port. You can also hack native code to replace text rendering, but this will be a hell of debugging ahead-

Comment: Actually, QOpenGLFunctions are very similar to QGLWidget  methods. Start there.

Comment: I have updated code to use QOpenGLWidget and used renderText api suggested in link [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216001/how-to-render-text-with-qopenglwidget . However, issue is still replicating. Please let me know if anybody has anymore suggestions.

Comment: There can be many QOpenGlWidgets/QGLwidgets in our application. We have used a single instance of QOpenGLContext/ QGLcontext which is shared by all the QOpenGLwidgets/QGLwidgets and is never deleted. Issue replicates when I delete a QOpenGLWidget/QGLwidget, and try to render text on another QOpenGlwidget.